# Replace conditional subquery in Order By (Performance consideration)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a ratings table (t2) I'm using to sort queries by `lower_bound DESC`. The problem is, the default value of `lower_bound` has to be `null` or `0`. When a rating occurs, the row is updated with Wilson's rating algo. This means that new entries get ordered before all other entries in a `lower_bound DESC` sort even though they have no rating yet (null or 0 is less than say, 0.2 and less is more in Wilson's rating algorithm).

To solve this, I added an `IF` statement and subquery which selects the row with the biggest `lower_bound` value and adds +1 to it. That way, new entries that have a null value for `lower_bound` are ordered last. It works but I want to avoid these kinds of queries wherever possible for performance reasons.

Can this `ORDER BY` be done in a more efficient manner, presumably without the subquery?

```
SELECT
    t1.*, t2.stars as rating
FROM
    table1 t1
JOIN
    table2 t2
    ON
        t2.user_id = t1.id
WHERE
    NOT t1.is_ready
ORDER BY
    IF(t2.lower_bound = NULL, (select lower_bound from t2 order by lower_bound asc)+1, t2.lower_bound)
        DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write your `ORDER BY` clause more efficiently by ordering first by whether `t2.lower_bound IS NULL` and then by the actual value i.e.

```
ORDER BY t2.lower_bound IS NULL, t2.lower_bound DESC
```

this will ensure that all entries with a `NULL` `lower_bound` value are sorted last, since `t2.lower_bound IS NULL` will be 1 for them while it is 0 for the non-`NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

I think another solution is to add a specialised column and using that column to order.

`(CASE WHEN t2.lower_bound IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS order_column`

And then add the `order_column` to your ORDER BY clause

`ORDER BY order_column`

I think this solution would perform better than using subqueries in your order by clause